# My game made by unity 2017.1.0f3 crash on launch on phone

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, crash, launch

Please please to help me in this problem, this is the error after crash on launch in phone after build:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/common/wrappers/Wrappers; at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzmn.zzg(Unknown Source) at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzmn.attachInfo(Unknown Source) at com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAdsInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown Source) at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6087) at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:5566) at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5505) at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap2(ActivityThread.java) at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1619) at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:163) at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6361) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904) at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794) Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.common.wrappers.Wrappers" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/net.run_boy_speed-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/net.run_boy_speed-1/lib/arm, /data/app/net.run_boy_speed-1/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]] at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56) at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380) at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312) ... 14 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Download a zip from here.
https://github.com/googlesamples/unity-jar-resolver

Then open it  & import the plugin that's residing there.
Then go to Assets > Play Services Resolver > Android > Force Resolve.

It must solve your problem.

Comment: I imported the plugin. after I get this :

Comment: Resolution failed

Failed to fetch the following dependencies:
com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier:17.0.0@aar
com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-sdk-api:17.0.0@aar
com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:17.0.0@aar
com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:17.0.0@aar

Comment: UnityEngine.Debug:LogError(Object)
Google.Logger:Log(String, LogLevel)
GooglePlayServices.PlayServicesResolver:Log(String, LogLevel)
GooglePlayServices.ResolverVer1_1:LogMissingDependenciesError(List`1)
GooglePlayServices.<DoResolutionUnsafe>c__AnonStorey18:<>m__26(List`1)
GooglePlayServices.<GradleResolution>c__AnonStorey14:<>m__1F(Result)
GooglePlayServices.<GradleResolution>c__AnonStorey15:<>m__28()
GooglePlayServices.PlayServicesResolver:PumpUpdateQueue()
UnityEditor.EditorApplication:Internal_CallUpdateFunctions()

Comment: Update Android Studio, Android SDK & SDK Tools.

Comment: Same problem here, i've updated everything, i've downgraded everything, nothing work so far. Current error is: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/common/wrappers/Wrappers;